# identação com highlight.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Estou com problemas em relação a indentação com highlight.js, o código esta sendo gerado pelo marked.js. Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe alguma solução?

index.html:

```
<!-- highlight.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/agate.min.css">
<!-- Codigo -->
<!-- Codigo -->
<!-- Codigo -->
<!-- Codigo -->
<script>
   hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
   var renderedElem = document.querySelector('.markdown-content');
   var renderedMD = marked(document.querySelector('.markdown-content').innerText);
   renderedElem.innerHTML = renderedMD;
</script>
```

Entrada:

```
.flow-text {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #424242;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem
}
```

No browser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código completo.

Comment: base.html: https://pastebin.com/33DHgYm8   /
home.html: https://pastebin.com/kzCaa2b6